# Can I describe a matrix multiplication as a transformation of one matrix by another?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Let's say I have two matrices $A$ and $B$, and I want to transform my vector $x$ by the product of $A$ and $B$. I could either first transform it by $A$ and then $B$, or multiply $A$ and $B$ $(A*B=C)$ and then transform $x$ by $C$. Would it be correct to say that in the second case I transformed $A$ using $B$ and got $C$, then used $C$ to transform my vector?
Can matrix multiplication be described as a transformation of the first matrix by the second?

Comment: Related: https://jpmccarthymaths.com/2017/09/29/why-do-we-multiply-matrices-like-we-do/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, that's a great question.

Second, it's a little bit muddled, so I'll try to sort it out for you.

Let's use "arrows with flags" ($\mapsto$) to indicate where transformations take things. So when you transform $x$ by $A$ and then $B$, you have

$$
x \mapsto Ax \mapsto B(Ax)
$$
i.e., you multiply $x$ by $A$ (on the left) and then multiply that by $B$ (on the left). Because you can regard $x$ as an $n \times 1$ matrix, this last item is really a product of three matrices ($A, B, $ and $x$), and matrix multiplication is associative, so we can rewrite and say that our composed operation is this:
$$
x \mapsto Ax \mapsto B(Ax) = (BA)x
$$
So the result of first transforming by $A$, and then transforming by $B$, is that you've transformed $x$ by the matrix $BA$. Notice how the order of the matrices is not what you expected in your question (namely, $AB$). But the associative law says that the one I've written is the one it *has* to be.

I'll just note that the transformation $x \mapsto Sx$ (for any matrix $S$) is a *linear* transformation: if we write 
$$
T(x) = Sx,
$$
then $T(x+y) = T(x) + T(y)$, and $T(cx) = c T(x)$ for any real number $c$. For that to make sense, we need to know a way to *add* vectors (so that $x+y$ makes sense) and a way to multiply them by real numbers, so that $cx$ makes sense. Hold that thought.

For later use, let's call the transformation defined by multiplication by the matrix $J$ by the name $T_J$, so that
$$
T_j : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n : x \mapsto Jx.
$$

So then my first diagram and the comment after it can be summarized by saying that

$$
T_B(T_A(x)) = T_{BA}(x)
$$
for any vector $x \in \Bbb R^n$.

You also asked another question, which was far more fun, in a way:

You've got an $n \times n$ matrix, $A$, from which you can generate a transformation of vectors. We can think of the set of all such matrices, which I'll call $M_{nn}$, as a set, and $A$ is just one element of this set. Now "left multiplication by $B$" is an operation on this set: it takes a matrix $Q$ and turns it into $BQ$, which is another matrix:
\begin{align}
M_{nn} &\to M_{nn}\\
Q &\mapsto BQ
\end{align}

Let's give this transformation a name, $H_B$, so 
$$
H_B: M_{nn} \to M_{nn} : Q \mapsto BQ
$$

It turns out that $H_B$ is *also* a linear transformation. For that to make sense, we need to know how to add elements of $M_{nn}$, i.e., how to add matrices, and how to multiply a matrix by a real number. Fortunately, we know both, and can write $H_B(Q + R) = H_B(Q) + H_B(R)$, for instance, which we prove using the distributive law for matrix multiplication.

And now your later observation amounts to saying this:

$$
T_{H_B(A)} = T_B \circ T_A
$$
or, in terms that involve an actual vector, $x \in \Bbb R^n$, it amounts to saying 
$$
T_{H_B(A)}(x) = T_B ( T_A (x)).
$$

But the former version is really more interesting: it says that the transformation $H$, acting on the set of all linear-transformations-on-$\Bbb R^n$, has a certain property that's related to composition-of-functions. So instead of discussing individual vectors, you've actually made a statement about a higher-level object, namely transformations. 
This is typical of the kind of "abstraction" that happens a lot as you advance in mathematics. Kudos to you for thinking of it early!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are certainly ways to see this. Gilbert Strang discusses various interpretations of matrix multiplication in [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FX4C-JpTFgY&index=3&list=PL49CF3715CB9EF31D)  Well, I'm pretty sure it's this lecture, but I haven't watched the videos recently.

I think you got a little confused with the or order of operations.  It seems  like you are computing  $ABx,$ so you would multiply $x$ by $B$ first, not by $A$.  If you want to consider $A$ as being transformed by $B$, think of $A$ as $<A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n>$ where the $A_i$ are the columns of $A$.  Then it's easy to see that the columns of $BA$ are just $<BA_1, BA_2, \dots,BA_n>.$  That is, we just apply $B$ to the columns of $A$.  Other possible interpretations are given in the lecture.